# Verificar se o registro já existe, se existir não altera o valor (MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**FUNÇÕES PHP**

```
<?
if($_REQUEST['salva_ed']){
    $sqlu="update registration set username='$username', firstname='$fname',  lastname='$lname', sex='$gender',
            birth_date='$bdate', addressline1='$address1',addressline2='$address2', complemento='$address3', numero='$address4', city='$city',  state='$state',
            country='$country', postcode='$zipcode', phone='$phone', mobile_no='$mobileno', full_mobileno='$fullmobile',
            email='$email', password=MD5('$pass'), cpf='$cpf',rg='$rg'  where id='$id'";
    $resultu=mysql_query($sqlu);
    header("location:message.php?msg=3"); exit;
}


if($_REQUEST['salva_nv']){
    $verifcode = md5($username);
    $agora=Date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $sqlu="insert into registration (username,firstname,lastname,sex,birth_date,addressline1,addressline2,city,state,
            country,postcode,phone,mobile_no,full_mobileno,email,password,cpf,rg,register_date,verify_code,
            final_bids,account_status,member_status,user_delete_flag,sponser,sms_flag,admin_user_flag) values
            ('$username','$fname','$lname','$gender','$bdate','$address1','$address2','$address3','$address4','$city','$state',
            '$country','$zipcode','$phone','$mobileno','$fullmobile','$email',MD5('$pass'),'$cpf','$rg','$agora','$verifcode',
            0,0,'0','',0,'0','0')";
            //echo $sqlu; exit;
    $resultu=mysql_query($sqlu);
    header("location:message.php?msg=2"); exit;
}
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<tr>
 <td class="normal" align="right"><font class="a">*</font>&nbsp;Senha de acesso:&nbsp;</td>
 <td><input style="width:60%" type="password" name="pass_word" value="<?=$pass?>"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td class="normal" align="right"><font class="a">*</font>&nbsp;Confirma&ccedil;&atilde;o de senha:&nbsp;</td>
 <td><input style="width:60%" type="password" name="cpassword" value="<?=$pass?>"/></td>
</tr>
    <input type="submit" value="Atualizar cadastro" name="Editar" class="bttn" /></td>
```

Pessoal, tenho um problema aqui e não consegui achar uma solução.

Este é um painel admin, eu implementei para ele salvar as senhas em MD5 no DB.

Existem duas funções, uma para executar quando for editar um cliente atual e outra para criar um novo cliente (salva_nv)...

O problema esta na função de editar o cliente (salva_ed), nos campos password.

Quando eu vou editar ele altera novamente a senha do cliente gerando uma outra MD5.

Como fazer para ele verificar se o registro é o mesmo na coluna, e não substituir a senha atual?

Ao carregar a página ele já preenche automaticamente os campos com a senha atual, porém ele mostra em MD5, então se eu salvar ele vai alterar no DB gerando uma nova chave MD5.

Vi na internet que é possível utilizar "constraint" para realizar essa tarefa, mas não consegui implementar.

Alguém tem alguma dica?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei fazer com constraint mas eu faria assim:

```
if($_REQUEST['salva_ed'] && $pass && $pass != ''){
$sqlu="update registration set username='$username', firstname='$fname',  lastname='$lname', sex='$gender',
        birth_date='$bdate', addressline1='$address1',addressline2='$address2', complemento='$address3', numero='$address4', city='$city',  state='$state',
        country='$country', postcode='$zipcode', phone='$phone', mobile_no='$mobileno', full_mobileno='$fullmobile',
        email='$email', password=MD5('$pass'), cpf='$cpf',rg='$rg' where id='$id' AND password != '$pass'";
$resultu=mysql_query($sqlu);
header("location:message.php?msg=3"); exit;
}
```

Dessa forma no where ele verifica se o password é diferente do que está sendo sugerido (sem converte-lo para md5)

Comment: Não funcionou aqui, fiz conforme mencionou mas ele continua salvando a senha... Toda vez que clico no botão salvar, ele altera o valor em "password" com uma nova MD5.

Comment: Funcionou aqui, eu copiei o seu código e colei aqui, ele ta com um erro no final, ta fora de "

Deixei dessa forma de funcionou:

where id='$id' AND password != '$pass'";

Muito obrigado cara, não achava que seria tão simples rsrs, valew!

Comment: Opa, marca a resposta como certa então valeu =]

Comment: Estou com um outro problema aqui, atualizei a pergunta pode me dar uma outra dica? rsrs

Comment: Cria outra pergunta, é importante manter o assunto atrelado ao titulo para pesquisas futuras.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode deixar um aviso no sistema falando para deixar em branco caso não queira alterar a senha e fazer assim:

```
    if($_REQUEST['salva_ed']){
if(!empty($pass){$sqlu="update registration set username='$username', firstname='$fname',  lastname='$lname', sex='$gender',
        birth_date='$bdate', addressline1='$address1',addressline2='$address2', complemento='$address3', numero='$address4', city='$city',  state='$state',
        country='$country', postcode='$zipcode', phone='$phone', mobile_no='$mobileno', full_mobileno='$fullmobile',
        email='$email', password=MD5('$pass'), cpf='$cpf',rg='$rg'  where id='$id'";}else{$sqlu="update registration set username='$username', firstname='$fname',  lastname='$lname', sex='$gender',
        birth_date='$bdate', addressline1='$address1',addressline2='$address2', complemento='$address3', numero='$address4', city='$city',  state='$state',
        country='$country', postcode='$zipcode', phone='$phone', mobile_no='$mobileno', full_mobileno='$fullmobile',
        email='$email', cpf='$cpf',rg='$rg'  where id='$id'";}
$resultu=mysql_query($sqlu);
header("location:message.php?msg=3"); exit;}
```

Comment: Estou com um outro problema aqui, atualizei a pergunta pode me dar uma outra dica? rsrS